# Data not being inserted into Android .db file despite successful transaction commit

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, android-sqlite, sql-insert

I am trying to insert data from a prepopulated database (EnglishVocabs.db) into table "vocab" of my Android app (app_database.db). I am using the following code to perform this operation:

```kotlin
        val appDbFile = context.getDatabasePath("app_database.db")
        val appdb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(appDbFile.path, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE)

        val insertUniqueVocabsSqlForAppDb = """
            ATTACH '${preDbFile.path}' AS preDb;

            INSERT INTO vocab(word, language_id, parts_json)
            SELECT DISTINCT B.word, ${Language.ENGLISH.id}, B.parts_json
            FROM preDb.EnglishVocabs AS B
            WHERE B.word NOT IN (SELECT A.word FROM vocab A);
        """.trimIndent()

        appdb.beginTransactionWithListener(object : SQLiteTransactionListener {
            override fun onBegin() {
                Logger.d("on begin")
            }
            override fun onCommit() {
                Logger.d("on commit")
            }
            override fun onRollback() {
                Logger.d("on rollback")
            }
        })

        try {
            Logger.d("attached db = ${appdb.attachedDbs}")
            val c = appdb.rawQuery(insertUniqueVocabsSqlForAppDb, arrayOf())
            appdb.setTransactionSuccessful()
            Logger.d("transaction success")

            if(c.moveToFirst()){
                Logger.d("response = ${c.getStringOrNull(0)}")
            }

            c.close()
        }catch (e: Exception){
            Logger.e(e.stackTraceToString())
        }finally {
            appdb.endTransaction()
            appdb.close()
        }
```

I am able to successfully run this code and the onCommit() method of the transaction listener is being called, indicating that the transaction has been committed.

[image]

However, when I go to check the app_database.db, the data has not been inserted.

[image]

Interestingly, when I copy both the prepopulated and app databases to my PC and run the SQL code using SQLite DB Browser, the data is inserted successfully (40k rows in 200ms). I am not sure what the issue could be in the Android environment. I've grant all necessary permissions.

[image]

Can anyone help me understand why this might be happening and how I can fix it?

UPDATE:
I use sqldelight as my app database. and I tried sqlDriver.execute()... too, nothing works
[image]

Comment: `am not sure what the issue could be in the Android environment` We too. But what is the issue? You could have told it.

Comment: I run this code on my pc, with the `BEGIN TRANSACTION` and `COMMIT` included of cources. it runs perfectly fine. I also check is path valid/exists, permissions, ... and nothing works, the `app_database.db` didn't change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `rawQuery()` is used to return rows and not for `INSERT` statements.

Instead you should use [`execSQL()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL%28java.lang.String%29) in 2 separate calls:

```
 appdb.execSQL("ATTACH '${preDbFile.path}' AS preDb");
 val insertUniqueVocabsSqlForAppDb = """
     INSERT INTO vocab(word, language_id, parts_json)
     SELECT DISTINCT B.word, ${Language.ENGLISH.id}, B.parts_json
     FROM preDb.EnglishVocabs AS B
     WHERE B.word NOT IN (SELECT A.word FROM vocab A);
 """.trimIndent()
 appdb.execSQL(insertUniqueVocabsSqlForAppDb)
```

Comment: no it's not works, I tried it before

Comment: @TorryDo I see that there are 2 statements in `insertUniqueVocabsSqlForAppDb`. You must separate them. See my edited answer.